# No such table SQLITE_SEQUENCE from AIR/Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, sqlite, air

I'm trying to reset the seed for an autoincrement field in SQLITE using AIR/ActionScript/Flex 4.5.

I'm doing what should normally work:

```
DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = 'myTable'
```

I've checked that the database actually contains a SQLITE_SEQUENCE table. I'm able to execute the above statement without errors directly via the Firefox SQLITE plugin (SQLite Manager).

However, when I try to do the same using actionscript, I get an error:

> No such table 'SQLITE_SEQUENCE'.

All I could find in searching around was this one guy who posted everywhere he could find - only to be left without an answer: 
[here](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://old.nabble.com/Unable-to-call-SQLITE_SEQUENCE-from-adbe-air-td23546850.html&ei=1alYToj9HaXhiALql5WmCQ&usg=AFQjCNG1fXEBfNNUwkXUMAHsxMaScVWB8w)
 and 
[here](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB4QFjAB&url=http://osdir.com/ml/sqlite-users/2009-05/msg00343.html&ei=1alYToj9HaXhiALql5WmCQ&usg=AFQjCNGzfmD7fSeWCMXlfMiP08NcBQsxBw)
 and 
[here](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEMQFjAG&url=http://forums.adobe.com/thread/429439&ei=1alYToj9HaXhiALql5WmCQ&usg=AFQjCNECBmuEing6Lj7JTUi0-G3NimWXJw)

Any ideas?

Comment: I was sure I had encountered this issue before, so I go searching through some old code, only to find this: `//select("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = '"+tableName+"' ");`. Nicely commented out :(

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an answer. I had to redesign parts of my app to expect the numbers to be in whatever order with missing ones in between - and I stopped making assumptions about the numbers (i.e what the starting number is etc).

Answer (score 17):

`sqlite_sequence` table is not created, until you define at least one autoincrement and primary key column in your schema.

Comment: If you have a `INTER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` column and always assign the PK manually, the `sqlite_sequence` appears not to be created either - and you can therefore insert rows for previously deleted PKs, because SQLite doesn't know about them any more.

Comment: Still true today in 2021. In my script I added `CREATE TABLE test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT); DROP TABLE test;` to create the `sqlite_sequence` table.

Comment: Amaizing ! Workaround with creating a table and deleting works!! 2021

Answer (score 0):

You should to insert "Auto increment" to primary key column
at least to one table,
Then SQLite is creating "SQLITE_SEQUENCE" table.

To get all tables have Auto increment:

```
SELECT * FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE;
```