# @capacitor-community/sqlite: Error: Query failed: SelectSQL: queryAll: no such table: sqlite_sequence when intializing app (web mode)

Tags: sql, angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor

#### Update:

So I am carefully comparing the working github starter with mine now, and I found the exact first line of code where the two states of our programs differ about databases:

in sqlite.service.ts in openDatabase(...):

```
db = await this.sqliteConnection
        .createConnection(dbName, encrypted, mode, version, readonly);
    }
    await db.open();
    console.log('HERE: the .values property: my program has 0 tables, the working program has 2 tables: ', 
      db.getTableList());
```

here u can see table list.values has the two desired tables:
[image: the working app]
here u can't see table list.values has the two desired tables:
[image: my app]

=> so the error is probably happening because this.sqliteConnection.createConnection() is NOT doing the right thing for me. But this is not my method but it is instead part of the library...

---

I followed this starter app which showcases how to use ionic-cap-sqlite:
https://github.com/jepiqueau/ionic-angular-sqlite-starter
and integrated all the stuff into my app. Actually I only took the part of employee-department and replaced those two entites with two of mine, I didnt take any of the posts-category code.

I forked the starter project and also got rid of the encryption/decryption stuff completely, without which all still works (I wanted to trim the error down to as little code as possible)

Now on init I am getting this:
`Error: Query failed: SelectSQL: queryAll: no such table: sqlite_sequence`

I read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17736785/20009330
and checked my sequences, and my upgrade statement (which creates the db tables) looks like this:

```
export const mapModeLocationVersionUpgrades = [
  {
    toVersion: 1,
    statements: [
      `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS map (
          id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        );`,
      `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mode (
          id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
          FOREIGN KEY (mapId) REFERENCES map (id)
        );`,
    ]
  },
]
```

The error happens when executing

```
const isData = await this.mDb.query("select * from sqlite_sequence");
```

Inside:

```
  async initializeDatabase() {
    // create upgrade statements
    await this.sqliteService // NOTE: this initializes
      .addUpgradeStatement({ database: this.databaseName,
        upgrade: this.versionUpgrades});
    // create and/or open the database
    await this.openDatabase();

    this.dbVerService.set(this.databaseName,this.loadToVersion);
    const isData = await this.mDb.query("select * from sqlite_sequence");
    // create database initial data
    if(isData.values!.length === 0) {
      await this.createInitialData();
    }
    if( this.sqliteService.platform === 'web') {
      await this.sqliteService.sqliteConnection.saveToStore(this.databaseName);
    }
    await this.getAllData();
  }
```

I am calling this when intializing the app through this here in `app.module.ts`:

```
export function initializeFactory(init: InitializeAppService) {
  return () => init.initializeApp();
}`
```

it's all as done in the starter project, there it works, not when doing it in my project though.

I am happy to provide more code however I cannot share my whole project as much as I would like to.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my CapacitorSQLitePlugin.addUpgradeStatement method failed (didn't create a table) because of a silly error in my upgrade sql-statement (I marked as a variable as a foreign key but I forgot to declare it as its own variable as well).

But there was no error thrown from the addUpgradeStatement method and then subsequent queries failed.